# Mobile App Avoiding or Securing CORS?

Tags: java, ajax, web-services, security, cors

I am wondering if there is an *industry standard* for better securing ajax calls on mobile.

My mobile app consists of my website's html, js, & css files -- but installs them locally on the mobile device for performance. The mobile devices' local index.html then calls my web server for data (Tomcat in this case).

The only way I have found this to work is to enable CORS in my servlet:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
```

But quite honestly, I dont like that for a variety of reasons but mainly -- anything can now query my webserver from *any domain* and get a response...

How can I achieve the same ajax call to my webserver from a mobile device using CORS - but in a more secure manner so that **only** my app is allowed access?

** OR ** Is CORS incorrect altogether in this case of mobile and there is a more standard/desirable solution?

Comment: "Anything can now query my webserver locally and get a response." Why is that a bad thing?

Comment: @KevinWorkman because then it becomes a public api of sorts, so more than just my website can call it. Am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I'm not a web guy. You got my upvote, since I think it's an interesting question and would like to know the answer myself. That being said, it sounds like you have two competing goals- you want a public API for yourself, but not for other people. What are you afraid people will do? Are there ways around that? Requiring a login maybe? API keys? Limits? Again, I have no idea what I'm talking about, but that's why I asked what exactly was bad about having a public API. It sounds like what you're describing as a problem is your entire goal in the first place, haha.

Comment: Thank you for your time on this, I really appreciate it... Yeah, I guess thats my question - can I make a CORS type call and keep it private. The more I read your comment the more I think API keys/oauth may be the only route..

Comment: As far as I know, only browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE...) are checking about CORS before issuing a cross domain request. Disabling CORS on your server may prevent me from creating a web client to your API on a different web site, but it wont prevent me from calling it with `curl`, `wget` or any programming language with an http client.

Answer (score 3):

CORS is a standard for instructing browsers on what to do when a page from another domain tries to access your domain.

The key term there is *browsers*. Anyone can construct a request (forging whatever headers they like, including `Origin`) that hits your server. What the Same Origin Policy and CORS rely on is a cooperative browser placing limits on what foreign scripts can do.

So the news is good. Since your code runs in a private web view in an app, you presumably don't face the risk of a foreign site running code in your view. (As opposed to browsers, where many domains run code in the same browser.)

So, as long as your code is running only on the app, CORS does not make your site any more or less vulnerable than it would be otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

While, OAuth is the enterprise/long term solutions. 
For a weekend project,

Can you think of restricting the methods to only GET or few which is needed, and also provide access to only specific resources?

Here is one workaround I used.

I had a similar problem for an angular js application on tomcat to interact with a restful, back end application.

I created a java application and hosted on the same tomcat where angular was hosted. This java application made calls to backend.
I later replaced the tomcat/java application with grunt and nodejs. Worked good.

nodejs, relay requests was 4 lines code :-)